# MySQL GUI Tool cannot load XML file

Tags: mysql, xml, database, browser

i try to run MySQL query browser but i got this error

cannot fetch datatype information

The data types file 'mysqlx_dbm_datatypes.xml' could not be loaded. you won't be able to use the table editor.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5DsQ.png)

i tried to uninstall and reinstall the app several times but nothing changed.
i tried to check the file location and there is no error there.

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Disable "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" in region settings.
It works for me.

Comment: I hesitated to try this answer first. But it worked really great.